# How to upload PDF to Google Drive using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

**Hello everyone
I want to upload via selenium PDF files automatically
In Python writing
Because Google Drive does not allow it to be done simply by SEND_KEYS
I would love to get help on how I can do this automatically**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver as wd


driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\l1313\\Desktop\\app\\chromedriver.exe")

p="C:\\Users\\l1313\\Desktop\\upload\\10.pdf"


driver.get("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxw2AvTpz4ksUIVPME3bWca5hp89sE3CjraDGJEu2c/dev")

time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/input[1]").send_keys(p)
```

Comment: If you dont have a requirement to use selenium I would suggest you drop it and just use google's api. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#python

Comment: ^ exactly. Why did you tag the question `[google-drive-api]` if you're not using it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a
"Application Script"
To create a upload file, but I need the file to upload automatically

If there is a possibility through Selenium I would like to hear

Thanks

Through this code
from HTML

> ```
> <base target="_top">   </head>   <body>
> <form>
> <input type="file" name="imageFile"/>
> <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="google.script.run.upload(this.parentNode)">
> </form>   </body> </html>
> ```

and this for code.gs

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("from.html")
  
}

function upload(e){
  //writing the logic to upload the image to drive
  
  var destination_id='1nTxvfpN1L0ZKqCyaFbiCSlcybnwMNteH' //folder id

  var img = e.imageFile

  var contentType = 'image/png'

  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id)
  
  var img = img.getAs(contentType)

  destination.createFile(img)
}
```

Comment: Up i need help plz